# How to execute sudo command every time I open terminal

Tags: 16.04, sudo, gnome-terminal, root, bashrc

I want to login as `root` with my user password every time I open `gnome-terminal`.
I don't like the separate window for typing password and I want to type the password straight into the terminal window.
After I login as `root` I want to load my user environment in my `.bashrc` file.

I wanted to program this with `sudo -s` command. The problem is I cannot put this command in my `.bashrc` file because it loads my `.bashrc` file again when executed. There must be more elegant solution. Can you help me?

Answer (score 2):

`gnome-terminal --command="sudo -s"`